# WM_Copy, wm_gettext and wm_keydown fail?

Tags: delphi, autohotkey, delphi-xe, sendmessage, te-edit

The problem: I need to obtain the selected text from a window in a Windows application (not my program). I am doing my work in Delphi XE and the software I am attempting to access is a kluge built over the past 15 years with C, C++, VB and who knows what else. I do not have the source code. The edit box (an RTF memo) I am attempting to read is of the class "Ter32Class". When I use **`wm_copy`**, nothing goes to the clipboard.  when I use **`wm_gettext`**, nothing. When I use **`wm_keydown`** commands (to simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) nothing happens.  Note that I can get all of these alternatives to work in wordpad, notepad, and FireFox but not this application (or OpenOffice, incidentally, but that's not the issue). The only way I have been able to programmatically obtain text from this box is to use autohotkey with the simple "`send ^c`" command.  While it works, it is inelegant. HELP?!?

More information: Window hierarchy: Ter32Class is a child of OI_Mdi which is a child of MDIClient, which is a child of OI_Window .  I am drilling down to obtain the appropriate handle as it will respond to a paste command.

I am using Delphi XE but I'd love any solution in C++ or VB if no Delphi XE gurus have the answer.

Comment: My guess is that AutoHotKey is using `SendInput` in order to correctly fake input. Perhaps this is one of those cases where sending WM_KEYDOWN commands isn't good enough. You may need to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Quick Macros Forum](http://www.quickmacros.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1390)

> One of the windows I need to talk to is of class Ter32Class which
>   apparently is a TE Edit Control, an editor that doesn't inherit from
>   the standard RichText Control

and

> The published method of talking to this control is via it's DLL

so unless something has changed *(post is 2006)*, it appears you'll need to use it's dll to get the text.

[From Sub Systems (TE Edit control website)](http://www.subsystems.com/tewf_api.htm)

> Application Interface functions
>
> **GetTerBuffer: Retrieve Window Text**
>          HANDLE GetTerBuffer(hWnd, size)

Comment: @David - I never used the component but as you are required to pass a hWnd to every function, I assumed it didn't matter what process owned the window.

Comment: Some possible concerns. There could be some global variables used by this code. With a separate process you have two instances of them. What if you had a different version of the DLL from the target app which had different data structures defined. Finally, lots of Windows API functions that receive window handles only work when called from that window's thread (i.e. the one that created it). Windows have thread affinity is the usual phrase to describe this.

Comment: @David - Valid concerns but as OP is only trying to read the text, global variables *should* not be an issue . I didn't know about  window handles being accessible only by the thread that created them, thanks. I'll leave the answer open for a while before deleting it. OP trying it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I don't know for sure it won't work, I just have some doubts.

Comment: This is encouraging and I'll try all of the above.  Thanks so much and I'll update when I've got some results.

Comment: An update: I confess to not yet trying the API but...  I reviewed additional options for sending text and found the following to work: `    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(ord('C'), 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(ord('C'), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
`

Comment: I was unable to get sendinput to work - I know that one will fail if the UIPI level is inadequate but I do not know if that is why it failed (no errorcode was given).

Comment: @Lieven: I tried the dll.  Obtaining the hwnd of the TE Edit control was trivial as was setting up the dll access but... I ran into an odd problem.  ter32.dll has some dependencies, some of which are mutual - not too sure about getting around this with dynamically loading the dll.  For example, it requires x.dll which requires y.dll.  y.dll requires x.dll.  y.dll won't load because x.dll isn't loaded (which won't load because y.dll isn't loaded). End result is ter32.dll won't load. I realize this branches off the original question. Should I make a new post?

Comment: @b-p - sorry for the delay but yes, it would be better to make it a new post. I would be interested to see the solution to that problem.

Comment: @lieven - done.  see [this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115930/get-around-3rd-party-cyclic-dll-dependencies)

Comment: keybd_event will work for sure if you do it right. It simply cannot fail. Did you give the other app the input focus?

Comment: @David - keybd_event is working but... I just hate to use the clipboard for this.  It would be neater to use getsel, gettext, setsel, etc. and it is frustrating to not be able to do this. I have to take into account delays (it only works with an adequate delay in place)