# Get around 3rd party cyclic dll dependencies?

Tags: delphi, dll, circular-dependency, cyclic-reference, te-edit

I am attempting to access text in a TE Edit (from ter32.dll) in a 3rd party application. (first post on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036292/wm-copy-wm-gettext-and-wm-keydown-fail))  I looked through the [API](http://www.subsystems.com/tewf_api.htm) and tried to dynamically load the dll in order to access a function. Unfortunately, this (aftermarket rework) of ter32.dll has a load of dependencies.  I tried dynamically loading each required dll as needed but ran into a cyclic dependency.  ter32.dll requires x.  x requires y.  y won't load because it requires x. Would I have to statically load these with a delay?  I sure hope not as I don't want the overhead/bloat/dependency in my application.

1) what am I missing?
2) is there some way around this?
3) does anybody have any other way of accessing the text in a TE Edit of ter32.dll?

Answer (score 3):

When you load a DLL the loader will load all the dependencies for you. These dependencies are listed in the import tables of each DLL and the loader resolves them. You don't need to do anything.

Therefore I can't understand how you came to the conclusion that you yourself needed to process DLL dependencies. Are you loading this DLL in a non-standard way? Do you need a manifest for WinSxS dependencies, i.e. if the MS C runtime is needed? Is there something else we need to know?

All that said, having this DLL loaded into your process is not likely, in my view, to help much in extracting text from a different process which has its own separate virtual memory. In other words, I am quite confident that your current attempt to extract the text will fail. The way to get around the virtual memory barrier is to run your code in the other process using a hook.

Comment: +1 Question: Could he use GetWindowText (exact name may differ) if he has the handle for the edit? He must already have the handle for the Window that hosts the edit (previous question). Can you somehow enumerate the handles "parented" by that window? If so and if he has some means of identifying the right one, he should be able to get there with the GetWindowText API?

Comment: @marjan this control is not subclassed from EDIT and doesn't return its contents from GetWindowText

Comment: @david - First, thanks - you have been very patient and a lot of help with my other posts.  I must be missing something here... (this is not my day job!)  I tried dynamically loading ter32.dll: `dllHandle := LoadLibrary(pwidechar(DllLocation + '\ter32.dll'));` and it said that x (I forget which) needed to be loaded first. So... I stumbled blindly along and dynamically loaded x before ter32.dll... and so on.  ran into the cyclic dependency.  Now... I just tried it again to get you the exact text of the error and it is loading the DLL.  Now to try the routines... Thanks!

Comment: @marjan - I appreciate the suggestion but... I tried it and as he said, TE Edit does not have the usual edit message handlers.

Comment: @david - Can you point me to a good resource to learn more about running my code in another process with a hook?

Comment: sorry no, I've no experience of this

Comment: @b-p: start with CreateRemoteThread. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437(VS.85).aspx ; and a discusion on codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx